# Client connects to server but server does not think client has connected in C++

Tags: c++, networking, client-server, mpi

I have a C++ program, using mpi, that follows a typical client server model. Each mpi instance of the client connects to a corresponding mpi instance of the server. This has worked relatively well until I have had to do some testing with added latency (1 second of added latency to be precise).

Problem:
Sometimes one of the server processes do not think the client has connected but the client thinks it has connected. i.e. After using gdb, the server is waiting at accept() but the client has continued on past connect(). Thus, it appears the client thinks it has connected when the server does not think it has connected.

My best guess is that I need to set an sock-option somewhere, however talking to fellow programmers and googling has not yielded any helpful results.

EDIT:
There are two sets of MPI processes (so two different calls to mpirun), the accept() and connect() calls are for the sockets, which are between the two sets of MPI processes. It is openmpi.

The code (from someone else's code, actually) [reduced]:

Client (connect code): (m_socket is the actual socket)

```
    if (-1 == m_socket)
    {
            perror("cannot create socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    res = inet_pton(AF_INET, host_ip, &addr.sin_addr);


    if (0 > res)
    {
            perror("error: first parameter is not a valid address family");
            close(m_socket);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (0 == res)
    {
            perror("error: second parameter does not contain valid IP address");
            close(m_socket);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //backoff 
    for (int sec = 1; sec < 20000; sec++ )
    {
            int ret;

            if (0 == (ret = connect(m_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))))
            {

                    return;
            }

            sleep(1);

            close(m_socket);
            m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    }

    perror("connect failed");
    close(m_socket);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Server: (m_socket is the actual socket)

```
    int socket = ::accept(m_socket, NULL, NULL);

    if(socket < 0)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            close(m_socket);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: Are the client and server running in different hosts? Are you sure you connected the client to the correct IP:port?

Comment: I am sure, it sometimes works and sometimes fails with the same run arguments. This is on the same host.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition to me... is your server code multithreaded?  If so, how is the multithreading handled with respect to the sockets?  Is it possible that the socket in question was returned by accept() and then fell through the cracks somehow, and so the server is back to blocking on accept() again while the "lost" socket isn't being handled by any other thread?

Comment: Each of the MPI processes has a single thread, each client MPI process has a single socket to the server MPI process. I don't know how it would have returned accept but then fallen back...

Comment: what MPI implementation are you using? It seems odd that yours exposes `accept()` and `connect()`.

Comment: There are two sets of MPI processes (so two different calls to mpirun), the accept() and connect() calls are for the sockets, which are between the two sets of MPI processes. 

It is openmpi.

Comment: @user put that in your question, it would also help if you add some code demonstrating the problem

Comment: Done and I added the connection code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do your connect/accept manually rather than with MPI. You might take a look at the example on Deino (http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Comm_accept.html) if you're trying to use MPI for your connections.

Alternatively, you might just need to look at a more general tutorial (some available here: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/tutorial/) of MPI to get a feel for how communication works. Most of the time and application doesn't use Connect/Accept to communicate, but uses MPI Communicators to set up communication mechanisms between processes. It's a different model (SPMD as opposed to MPMD).